# Custom user variable for user object

Tags: drupal

How can I add a custom user variable for the user object? I want something that a user can customize in their profile page and that I can retrieve in the user object in another module, for example a preference for currency USD or EURO.

I would accept the simplest idea that doesn't involve writing a module, unless is no other way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the **Profile** module to define additional settings that users will be able to edit in their profile page and will be available in the `$user` object: http://drupal.org/documentation/modules/profile

Furthemore, you should read [How to create new profile fields](http://drupal.org/node/23710).

Comment: looks like the right thing. I'll try it and come back to you. Thanks.